# Parent rotation for specific child position and rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a character that can only turn on the Y-axis, so left and right basically, if up is Vector3.up. The character has a child which is the position where grenades spawn (his right hand), and now I'm trying to figure out how I can calculate the correct rotation for the parent so the child looks exactly at a target, but only "horizontally". The x and z rotation of the parent must be 0. Is there a way to do that? It's fine if the child only looks into the correct direction on the "horizontal plane", but doesn't look up or down to face the target perfectly.

This answer almost does what I want: http://answers.unity.com/comments/1339850/view.html

The only problem is that the resulting rotation is a mix of all three axes, instead of it being just a y-rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use trigonometry to solve this. Explanation in comments:

```
Vector3 rotAxis = Vector3.up;

// flatten child pos, target pos, char pos, and child forward.
Vector3 flatChildPos = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(childTransform.position, rotAxis);
Vector3 flatTargetPos = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(targetTransform.position, rotAxis);
Vector3 flatCharPos = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(charTransform.position, rotAxis);
Vector3 flatChildForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(childTransform.forward, rotAxis);

Vector3 flatCharToTarget = flatTargetPos-flatCharPos;
Vector3 flatChildToChar = flatCharPos-flatChildPos;

// Find the angle going from the direction of child to parent to the child's forward
// The sign will come in handy later
float childAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(flatChildToChar, flatChildForward,
        rotAxis);
float absChildAngle = Mathf.Abs(childAngle);

// Find the distance between child and character:
float childDist = flatChildToChar.magnitude;

// Find the distance between character and target:
float targetDist = flatCharToTarget.magnitude;

// Consider the triangle made by character position, position of target, and
// desired child position. Use sin rule to find angle of target's corner
float targetAngle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Asin(
        Mathf.Sin(absChildAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)
        * childDist/targetDist);

// determine angle in parent's corner:
float desiredParentAngle = 180f - absChildAngle - targetAngle;

// Determine sign of angle at character from target to child. 
// It's the same as the sign of angle at child from char to target.
float sign = Mathf.Sign(childAngle);

// Consider the triangle made by character position, position of target, and 
// current child position. Determine the current signed angle in character corner.
float currentParentAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(flatCharToTarget, -flatChildToChar, 
        rotAxis);

// Calculate the diff in angle needed to make the current triangle the desired one.
float diffAngle = desiredParentAngle * sign - currentParentAngle;

// Apply the diff in world space
Quaternion newRot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(diffAngle, rotAxis) * charTransform.rotation;
```

Interestingly, in some situations there maybe two possible rotations. Determining when that is the case and what the second rotation is left as an exercise to the reader. Hint: there are sometimes multiple valid values for `targetAngle` and `desiredParentAngle` also ;)

Comment: @Lyxodius Ah, I forgot to convert between degrees and radians. This should work now!!!

Comment: Wow, this actually works!
I'm completely amazed!
I've been working two days on this, and finally it works!
Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you would just have to invert the child's [`localEulerAngles.y`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)

The [`localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) are the child's offset rotation in euler angles relative to its parent. So taking only the `y` component already tells you the child's offset against its parent.

So I guess in order to rotate the parent back accordingly you would do e.g.

```c#
// as usual get the direction from child to target
var targetDirection = targetObject.transform.position - childObject.transform.position;

// flatten the direction by erasing any difference in the Y-axis
var targetDirectionFlat = Vector3.Scale(new Vector3(1,0,1), targetDirection).normalized;

// get the Y angle offset between parent and child 
var offset = -childObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y;

// rotate the parent to face the flattened direction minus the offset
// both are rotations around the Y axis only
parent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookDirection(targetDirectionFlat) * Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * offset);
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the ides gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It seems to almost work, but for some reason there is a quite substantial accuracy error.
https://imgur.com/QYlGxk8
The top line is the child.forward and the bottom one the parent.forward.
The child.forward is supposed to go exactly through the center of the target on the picture.

Comment: @derHugo I think you made the same mistake I did on my first attempt in that I didn't account for how the local position for the child is nonzero. You need to account for the change in world position of the child depending on the rotation of the parent. See my answer for how I used trig to solve that problem :)

Comment: @Ruzihm yeah actually that wasn't a mistake ^^ I see now from the comment that OP wanted it but since he stated that the one from the URL was almost the goal except he wanted to ignore the difference in Y I gave the answer more based under the assumption only rotation matters in this use case ^^ I see now the assumption was wrong :D