# Rotate parent so child faces point in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to rotate a parent GameObject along it's z axis in Unity so that a child of that object faces a certain target point.

This piece of code works as long as the child's position is zeroed out. The script is attached to the parent object, and I'm working in a 2D project.

```
Vector3 parentDir = (targetPoint - transform.position).normalized;
offset = Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, child.transform.right);
float rotationZ = (Mathf.Atan2(parentDir .y, parentDir .x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) - offset;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationZ);
```

When the child's position is not zero however, for the `offset` value it obviously won't be enough to calculat the signed angle between the parent and child's x axes, but I cannot wrap my head around the problem.

[This answer looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938999/parent-rotation-for-specific-child-position-and-rotation), but I just cannot seem to convert the 3D part of it to 2D.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _child;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _target;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Can be cached (Start/Awake) if relative child position not changed.
        var childToParent = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(_child.rotation);

        var directionTarget = (_target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        var angleToTarget = Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.right, directionTarget, Vector3.forward);
        var toTargetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleToTarget, Vector3.forward);

        transform.rotation = childToParent * toTargetRotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution however also only works if the child's local position is zeroed out.